# How to add colMeans result to last line preserving data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have this df:

```
df <- data.frame(colA=c("A","B","C"),
colB = c("Stringn","Stringc","Stringb"),
x2008 = c(2.71472,1.62307,1.62269),
x2009 = c(NA,1.68250,1.66570))

df%>%
select(`x2008`,`x2009`)%>%
colMeans (na.rm = T)
```

Return:

| x2008 | x2009 |
| --- | --- |
| 1.986827 | 1.674100 |

Expected return:

| colA | colB | x2008 | x2009 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Stringn | 2.71472 | NA |
| B | Stringc | 1.62307 | 1.6825 |
| C | Stringd | 1.62269 | 1.6657 |
| Average | result | 1.986827 | 1.674100 |

I am doing this:

```
df%>%
select(`x2008`,`x2009`)%>%
colMeans (na.rm = T)%>%
mutate (`ColA` =" Average ",` ColB` = "result")
```

But it gives error, any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last but not least:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  add_row(colA = "Average", colB = "Result", x2008 = mean(df$x2008, na.rm = TRUE),
          x2009 = mean(df$x2009, na.rm = TRUE))

     colA    colB    x2008  x2009
1       A Stringn 2.714720     NA
2       B Stringc 1.623070 1.6825
3       C Stringb 1.622690 1.6657
4 Average  Result 1.986827 1.6741
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is `summarise`, which can return more than one row and if needed expand the row.  So, we loop `across` the columns that `starts_with` 'x', concatenate the original value  (`.`) with `mean` of that column value, while concatenating the 'colA', 'colB' separately with 'Average' and 'result' string

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   summarise(colA = c(colA, 'Average'), colB = c(colB, 'result'), 
      across(starts_with('x'), ~ c(., mean(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```

-output

```
   colA     colB    x2008  x2009
1    A    Stringn 2.714720     NA
2    B    Stringc 1.623070 1.6825
3    C    Stringb 1.622690 1.6657
4 Average result 1.986827 1.6741
```

---

Another option is to bind the output from the OP's code with the original data and then replace the `NA` in 'colA', 'colB' with a new string

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    select(starts_with('x')) %>% 
    colMeans(na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
    bind_rows(df, .) %>% 
    mutate(colA = replace_na(colA, 'Average'), 
           colB = replace_na(colB, 'result'))
```

-output

```
     colA    colB    x2008  x2009
1       A Stringn 2.714720     NA
2       B Stringc 1.623070 1.6825
3       C Stringb 1.622690 1.6657
4 Average  result 1.986827 1.6741
```

---

We may also use [`grand_summary_rows`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gt/versions/0.3.0/topics/grand_summary_rows)

```
library(gt)
df %>% 
    gt() %>%
    grand_summary_rows(columns = c(x2008, x2009), 
           fns = list(Average =  ~ mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

-output

[image]